# Enable/Disable a network adapter with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I started out trying to use a shortcut to display the **Local Area Connection Status** window on my desktop by creating a shortcut and assigning it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma).

Windows didn't like that, so it added <kbd>Alt</kbd>, which ended up being <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.

Since I couldn't figure out a way to eliminate <kbd>Alt</kbd> as part of the shortcut keys, I am now trying a different strategy and it's not working. My latest attempt is to use AutoHotkey with the following command:

```
^,::Run, explorer ::{BA126ADB-2166-11D1-B1D0-00805FC1270E}
```

Which is what the shortcut target number is, but it won't open the window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am going to list the manual steps necessary to quickly enable or disable a network adapter. Then, I will translate these steps into [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

---

### By hand:

1. Open **Network Connections** from the command line.

   ```
   explorer ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}
   ```

   [image: Network Connections]
2. Once the window is active, **press** <kbd>Space</kbd> to set the focus to the list of adapters.

   [image: list]
3. If the adapter you want to enable/disable is currently selected (i.e. the **1st`** on the list), skip to **Step #5**.
4. If the adapter is not selected, **press** <kbd>Right</kbd> until it is selected. For example press <kbd>Right</kbd> **1 time** if the adapter is **2nd** on the list, **2 times** if it is **3rd**, etc.

   [image: 2nd]
5. **Right-click** the adapter and **press** <kbd>Down</kbd> to highlight the `Enable` or `Disable` option.

   [image: disable]

   [image: enable]
6. **Press** <kbd>Enter</kbd> to `Enable` or `Disable`.
7. **Close** Network Connections.

---

### Autohotkey:

Using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```
^,::

   ;1.
   Run, explorer ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}

   ;2.
   WinWaitActive, Network Connections
   Send, {Space}

   ;3. & 4.
   ;If the adapter is not the 1st, navigate to it.
   ;For example, without the comment (semi-colon):
   ;    Send, {Right 1}
   ;if it is the 2nd adapter.
   ;    Send, {Right 2}
   ;if it is the 3rd, etc.

   ;5.
   Send, {AppsKey}
   Sleep, 250 ;adjust as needed
   Send, {Down}

   ;6.
   Send, {Enter}

   ;7.
   WinClose, Network Connections

   return
```

Comment: Thought it might be nice to mention you can even go "total keyboard" if you use the keyboard for the "right click" in step 5, using either the "right click" key if your keyboard has one, or "Shift+F10" if your keyboard doesn't have one (e.g. in a VM running on a Mac).

Comment: It wasn't working for me at the beginning. I'm on Windows 10. I modified step 6 with another sleep command and then it worked fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Just go to the screen where the adapter icon is located. Right click and create shortcut (it won't allow to add shortcut to that window but it will allow it to be created in desktop). When you want to enable or disable the adapter just right click the icon on your desktop and click enable or disable.

Comment: The "screen where the adapter icon is located" in this case is Network and Internet\Network Connections. Open Network and Sharing Center and then click on "Change adapter settings" in the left pane.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an easy way to enable or disable your NIC (or other device for that matter), that bypasses the Control Panel, Device Manager, and other windows altogether, you can do so with a a batch file:

1. Get a copy of Microsoft’s [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) utility
2. Create and save the following batch file (e.g., as `ToggleNIC.bat`)

   ```
   @echo off
   if (%1)==(+) goto enable
   if (%1)==(-) goto disable
   goto :eof

   :: Replace the device ID ("VEN_1234&DEV_5678" in the example) with that of your own NIC.
   :: You can find it with the command "devcon find PCI*", looking for the name of your NIC.

   :: When you locate your device ID, enter only up to the "DEV"; that should be enough to uniquely identify the device.
   :: Leave the "SUBSYS" and later parts of the string off, otherwise it may not work.

   :enable
       devcon enable  "PCI\VEN_1234&DEV_5678"
       goto :eof

   :disable
       devcon disable "PCI\VEN_1234&DEV_5678"
       goto :eof
   ```
3. Create two shortcuts to the batch file (e.g., `EnableNIC.lnk` and `DisableNIC.lnk`), in one specifying the *Target* field as `C:\…\ToggleNIC.bat +` and for the other, `C:\…\ToggleNIC.bat -` (of course replace the `…` with the path to the batch file)
4. Set a hotkey in the *Properties* dialog for each shortcut—<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Num+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Num-</kbd> seem like good, logical ones.

   - (There’s a reason Explorer tries to prevent simple shortcuts of the form <kbd>Ctrl+Key</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+Key</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift+Key</kbd>; because those are normally used in programs for everyday tasks, so using them as shell hotkeys would cause no end of trouble. But, if you *really* need one without <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you can manually hack the `.lnk` file or easier, just use a macro/hotkey program to create a task to run the batch files with whatever hotkey you like.)
5. Alternately, you could put the batch file somewhere in your PATH, then you can simply toggle the NIC via the *Start* menu or *Run* dialog; e.g. <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, `togglenic +`

You can also make it so that the batch file literally toggles the NIC (enable it if it is currently disabled, or disable it if it is currently enabled), but that will be a little more involved and probably not necessary in general.

Answer (score 0):

iglvzx's post didn't quite work for me at first, but with a little tweaking, it works for me now. The shortcut works as a toggle switch for the wired network adapter (disable / enable). Still activated by Ctrl + J, as seen in the first line. If you don't have a bluetooth adapter, then you will have to delete line 3. If you have an additional adapter or you want to target your wireless adapter, you may need to add "{Right 1}". Alternatively, just change the number of right inputs in line ;3.

```
^j::

   ;1.
   Run, explorer ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}

   ;2.
   WinWaitActive, Network Connections
   Send, {Space}

   ;3.
   Send, {Right 1}

   ;4.
   Send, {AppsKey}
   Sleep, 250 ;adjust as needed
   Send, {Down}

   ;5.
   Send, {Enter}

   ;6.
   WinClose, Network Connections

   return
```