# Disabled network via software

Tags: windows-7, networking

I work mainly offline, and I find it tiresome having to go to:

- "Open network and sharing center"
- "Change adapter settings"
- "Selecting the network icon"
- *"enable or disable the connection"

and then having to go through that cycle again and again.....

Question:

I would like to make a button or switch that sits on my desktop.

The button should have a "on/off" function to switch network connection
on and off. (cable connection!) not wifi. It doesn't have to be visual all the time (like on top of programs) only on the desktop.

I'm only a beginner programmer, I dabble a little in Visual Studio 2012
C#, I have tried a few times, but I lack the experience and know how.

Comment: Unplug the cable.

Comment: What you want more or less exists in XP: if you right-click on the network icon in the system tray, there is a disable/enable option. Sadly, MS in their wisdom removed this from later releases.

Answer (score 3):

Easy, just right click the connection, select "create shortcut" and leave it on the desktop. Then all you have to to is right click it from there and do enable or disable. If you really wanted to get fancy, you could change the icon to an "on/off" button? Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple solution

Just create two batch files and put shortcuts on your desktop.

lanoff.cmd

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" disabled
```

lanon.cmd:

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" enabled
```

---

#### Advanced solution

See [Enable/Disable a network adapter with a keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/403620/enable-disable-a-network-adapter-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering so soon,

Unplugging the cable is not really a suitable option for me, as I am using a desktop and the computer is underneath the bureau. I thought of adding a switch-box to my desk between the computer and router, but that would interfere with my cable speed.

The easiest way would be a shortcut to right-click, like the XP. But, as I'm learning how to program in C#, I recalled this thought last year and wanted to experiment. "The Windows CMD index" will be a great help for when I do finally get more experience with Visual Studio.

But, till then I will have to go with the batch suggestion, until I learn to code, Or find a code that would do the same thing.

After googling for it, it seems (apart from me) nobody misses the XP option. (AFH)

Thank you all again, its the first time I've ever posted a question. And this was very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please use the **Post Your Answer** button only for actual answers. You should [edit] your original post to add additional information.